# SD card appears and dissapear after inserting it

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card, corruption, ddrescue

I have a 16GB Kingston SDHC from a Canon SX40 that seems to be corrupted or has a hardware failure.

Camera shows only a few photos and videos (and something that camera says it can't read). But there's a lot more of photos that I want/need to get from there (birthday of my mother with a friend of her who now lives far away).

When I connect SD to a card reader, file explorer (Caja) is opened automatically and, after a couple of seconds, it closes. In that seconds, I can even double click in DCMI folder and can see what's inside... but nothing else.

In that seconds, /sdb1 appears in /dev, but then it dissapears. Nor Gparted nor Photorec can read it. Also, dd can't read from sdb, it says:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=tarjeta.img bs=512
dd: No se puede abrir '/dev/sdb': No se ha encontrado el medio
```

Another try:

```
$ sudo ddrescue -dr3 /dev/sdb card.image logfile
ddrescue: Can't open input file: No medium found
```

Another try with ddrescue, this time, in "that seconds"... till it dissapears:

```
$ sudo ddrescue -dr3 /dev/sdb card.image logfile
GNU ddrescue 1.24
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
     ipos:   10747 kB, non-trimmed:   78708 kB,  current rate:       0 B/s
     opos:   10747 kB, non-scraped:        0 B,  average rate:   2149 kB/s
non-tried:        0 B,  bad-sector:        0 B,    error rate:  85393 kB/s
  rescued:   10747 kB,   bad areas:        0,        run time:          4s
pct rescued:    0.06%, read errors:     1402,  remaining time:         n/a
                              time since last successful read:          0s
Trimming failed blocks... (forwards)          
ddrescue: Unaligned read error. Is sector size correct?
```

This is dmseg from when insert card:

```
[67030.250419] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 31047680 512-byte logical blocks: (15.9 GB/14.8 GiB)
[67030.252183] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[67030.252188] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 4b 00 00 08
[67030.258544]  sdb: sdb1
[67030.956050] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[67035.709902] scsi_io_completion: 119 callbacks suppressed
[67035.709908] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[67035.709911] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[67035.709914] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
[67035.709917] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 89 6a 41 00 00 01 00
[67035.709918] blk_update_request: 119 callbacks suppressed
[67035.709920] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 25782849
[67035.846388] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[67035.846391] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[67035.846394] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
[67035.846397] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 89 6a 42 00 00 01 00
[67035.846400] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 25782850
[67035.982878] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[67035.982883] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[67035.982886] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
[67035.982890] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 89 6a 43 00 00 01 00
[67035.982893] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 25782851
[67036.119373] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[67036.119377] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[67036.119380] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
[67036.119383] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 89 6a 44 00 00 01 00
[67036.119385] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 25782852
[67036.277084] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[67036.277088] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[67036.277092] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
[67036.277096] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 89 6a 45 00 00 01 00
[67036.277098] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 25782853
[67036.278149] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[67036.278153] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[67036.278156] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[67036.278159] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 89 6a 46 00 00 01 00
[67036.278162] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 25782854
[67036.279195] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[67036.279197] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[67036.279200] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[67036.279203] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 89 6a 47 00 00 02 00
[67036.279205] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 25782855
[67036.280326] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[67036.280330] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[67036.280333] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[67036.280336] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 89 6a 48 00 00 01 00
[67036.280338] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 25782856
[67036.281448] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[67036.281451] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[67036.281454] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[67036.281457] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 89 6a 49 00 00 01 00
[67036.281459] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 25782857
[67036.282445] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[67036.282448] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[67036.282451] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[67036.282454] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 89 6a 4a 00 00 01 00
[67036.282456] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 25782858
[67036.341825] FAT-fs (sdb1): Directory bread(block 25774657) failed
[67036.342819] FAT-fs (sdb1): Directory bread(block 25774658) failed
[67036.344750] FAT-fs (sdb1): Directory bread(block 25774659) failed
[67036.345900] FAT-fs (sdb1): Directory bread(block 25774660) failed
[67036.346943] FAT-fs (sdb1): Directory bread(block 25774661) failed
[67036.348077] FAT-fs (sdb1): Directory bread(block 25774662) failed
[67036.349069] FAT-fs (sdb1): Directory bread(block 25774663) failed
[67036.350169] FAT-fs (sdb1): Directory bread(block 25774664) failed
[67036.351453] FAT-fs (sdb1): Directory bread(block 25774665) failed
[67036.352443] FAT-fs (sdb1): Directory bread(block 25774666) failed
[67036.409693] FAT-fs (sdb1): error, corrupted directory (invalid entries)
[67036.409699] FAT-fs (sdb1): Filesystem has been set read-only
[67036.443807] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 3759, lost async page write
[67036.471054] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 7548, lost async page write
[67037.040148] VFS: Dirty inode writeback failed for block device sdb1 (err=-5).
```

Is there something else I can try to get images/videos from inside it?

OS: Debian Stretch x64 Mate.

Comment: I agree that the card seems to have some hardware problem. It's not just corrupt in the typical sense that it has bad blocks. So this is not the right forum for the question. What you can try is to clean the contacts or to use a different Adapter to read it. If both doesn't help, I would use some embedded system with a native MMC interface. This way you can debug the problem on a lower level and maybe find some brute-force way to read each block over and over until you have a complete image of the card.

Comment: As you said, @Philippos, I tried with another card reader (Bus 001 Device 004: ID 048d:1336 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. SD/MMC Cardreader) and it read it right! I made an image with ddrescue and rescue photos with photorec. Now, I'm trying to repair video files, because they are all broken. Thanks!